# Problem with subtracting value from previous row in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having problems with using `dplyr` to subtract a value from the previous row.

#### The dataframe is as follows:

```
graph_data_frame1

# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   Trade_Date [10]
  Trade_Date          B_S   Lots_Total Avg_Price   atr
  <dttm>              <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    
 1 2017-12-11 00:00:00 B             88     3591   43.3
 2 2017-12-11 00:00:00 S             88     3586   43.3
 3 2017-12-08 00:00:00 B            176     3594   40.7
 4 2017-12-08 00:00:00 S            176     3599.  40.7
 5 2017-12-07 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3
 6 2017-12-06 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   41.8
 7 2017-12-05 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3
 8 2017-12-04 00:00:00 B             44     3563   39.5
 9 2017-12-04 00:00:00 S             44     3569   39.5
10 2017-12-01 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   42.7
11 2017-11-30 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   46.2
12 2017-11-29 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.2
13 2017-11-28 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.3
```

#### The code I am using is:

```
atr_diff_df <- graph_data_frame1 %>%
  group_by(Trade_Date) %>%
  arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>%
  mutate(atr_diff = atr - lag(atr, default = first(atr)))
```

#### The result created by mutate is all zeroes:

```
 atr_diff_df
 # A tibble: 13 x 6
 # Groups:   Trade_Date [10]  
    Trade_Date          B_S   Lots_Total Avg_Price   atr atr_diff
    <dttm>              <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
  1 2017-12-11 00:00:00 B             88     3591   43.3        0
  2 2017-12-11 00:00:00 S             88     3586   43.3        0
  3 2017-12-08 00:00:00 B            176     3594   40.7        0
  4 2017-12-08 00:00:00 S            176     3599.  40.7        0
  5 2017-12-07 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3        0
  6 2017-12-06 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   41.8        0
  7 2017-12-05 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3        0
  8 2017-12-04 00:00:00 B             44     3563   39.5        0
  9 2017-12-04 00:00:00 S             44     3569   39.5        0
 10 2017-12-01 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   42.7        0
 11 2017-11-30 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   46.2        0
 12 2017-11-29 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.2        0     
 13 2017-11-28 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.3        0
```

#### Desired Result:

```
 graph_data_frame1
 # A tibble: 13 x 6
 # Groups:   Trade_Date [10]
    Trade_Date          B_S   Lots_Total Avg_Price   atr atr_diff
   <dttm>              <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
  1 2017-12-11 00:00:00 B             88     3591   43.3    0    
  2 2017-12-11 00:00:00 S             88     3586   43.3    2.61 
  3 2017-12-08 00:00:00 B            176     3594   40.7    0    
  4 2017-12-08 00:00:00 S            176     3599.  40.7    0.382
  5 2017-12-07 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3   -1.53 
  6 2017-12-06 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   41.8    1.55 
  7 2017-12-05 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3    0.754
  8 2017-12-04 00:00:00 B             44     3563   39.5    0    
  9 2017-12-04 00:00:00 S             44     3569   39.5   -3.21 
 10 2017-12-01 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   42.7   -3.47 
 11 2017-11-30 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   46.2   -0.971
 12 2017-11-29 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.2   -0.118
 13 2017-11-28 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.3   NA
```

I am able to get my desired result with base R but would like to use dplyr.

#### Data (ungrouped):

```
structure(list(Trade_Date = structure(c(1512950400, 1512950400, 
1512691200, 1512691200, 1512604800, 1512518400, 1512432000, 1512345600, 
1512345600, 1512086400, 1.512e+09, 1511913600, 1511827200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), B_S = c("B", "S", "B", "S", NA, NA, 
NA, "B", "S", NA, NA, NA, NA), Lots_Total = c(88, 88, 176, 176, 
NA, NA, NA, 44, 44, NA, NA, NA, NA), Avg_Price = c(3591, 3586, 
3594, 3598.85714285714, NA, NA, NA, 3563, 3569, NA, NA, NA, NA
), atr = c(43.2857142857143, 43.2857142857143, 40.6734693877551, 
40.6734693877551, 40.2915451895044, 41.8213244481466, 40.2754209555542, 
39.5217893904751, 39.5217893904751, 42.7329623346929, 46.1996820011654, 
47.1711560009989, 47.2895622865705)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Please include the actual data with `dput(graph_data_frame1)` so we can hep you and also an example of the desired output

Comment: Could you try it without the `group_by` statement, please

Comment: I took out the group_by statement and got the same result

Comment: please don't just post the dataframe. Use dput like I said. Much easier to read into R

Comment: This is my first post; how do I use dput?

Comment: type `dput(graph_data_frame1)` and paste the result into the question

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with `group_by()` call. Looking at your data (I did `ungroup(dat)` on your `dput()` output), I can see that *for each group*, defined by `group_by(Trade_Date)` your `atr` variable's length is either 1 or 2. In former case, both values are identical. So when you call `lag(atr, default = first(atr))` within your `mutate()` function it returns two values *identical* to corresponding values in `attr`, within the defined group, when there are 2 values in group, or just one value *identical* to the first (and only one) value of `attr`, if length of `attr` within the defined group is equal to 1. Which means, that when you do the subtraction you always subtract identical values, which obviously produces `0`.

So look what is going on when you do group your data:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Trade_Date) %>%
  arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>%
  mutate(first_term = atr, second_term = lag(atr, default = first(atr)),
         difference = atr - lag(atr, default = first(atr)))

# # A tibble: 13 x 8
# # Groups:   Trade_Date [10]
#   Trade_Date          B_S   Lots_Total Avg_Price   atr first_term second_term difference
#   <dttm>              <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 2017-12-11 00:00:00 B             88     3591   43.3       43.3        43.3          0
# 2 2017-12-11 00:00:00 S             88     3586   43.3       43.3        43.3          0
# 3 2017-12-08 00:00:00 B            176     3594   40.7       40.7        40.7          0
# 4 2017-12-08 00:00:00 S            176     3599.  40.7       40.7        40.7          0
# 5 2017-12-07 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3       40.3        40.3          0
# 6 2017-12-06 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   41.8       41.8        41.8          0
# 7 2017-12-05 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3       40.3        40.3          0
# 8 2017-12-04 00:00:00 B             44     3563   39.5       39.5        39.5          0
# 9 2017-12-04 00:00:00 S             44     3569   39.5       39.5        39.5          0
#10 2017-12-01 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   42.7       42.7        42.7          0
#11 2017-11-30 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   46.2       46.2        46.2          0
#12 2017-11-29 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.2       47.2        47.2          0
#13 2017-11-28 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.3       47.3        47.3          0
```

And without grouping:

```
dat %>%
  arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>%
  mutate(first_term = atr, second_term = lag(atr, default = first(atr)),
         difference = atr - lag(atr, default = first(atr)))

# # A tibble: 13 x 8
#   Trade_Date          B_S   Lots_Total Avg_Price   atr first_term second_term difference
#   <dttm>              <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 2017-12-11 00:00:00 B             88     3591   43.3       43.3        43.3      0    
# 2 2017-12-11 00:00:00 S             88     3586   43.3       43.3        43.3      0    
# 3 2017-12-08 00:00:00 B            176     3594   40.7       40.7        43.3     -2.61 
# 4 2017-12-08 00:00:00 S            176     3599.  40.7       40.7        40.7      0    
# 5 2017-12-07 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3       40.3        40.7     -0.382
# 6 2017-12-06 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   41.8       41.8        40.3      1.53 
# 7 2017-12-05 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3       40.3        41.8     -1.55 
# 8 2017-12-04 00:00:00 B             44     3563   39.5       39.5        40.3     -0.754
# 9 2017-12-04 00:00:00 S             44     3569   39.5       39.5        39.5      0    
#10 2017-12-01 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   42.7       42.7        39.5      3.21 
#11 2017-11-30 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   46.2       46.2        42.7      3.47 
#12 2017-11-29 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.2       47.2        46.2      0.971
#13 2017-11-28 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.3       47.3        47.2      0.118
```

See that the resulting vector is not zeros anymore.

It's absolutely unclear to me, what kind of transformation do you want to perform on your data, and why you do want to do it this way. But you can obtain your desired output this way:

```
dat %>%
  arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>%
  mutate(first_term = atr, second_term = lag(atr, default = first(atr)),
         difference = atr - lead(atr))

# # A tibble: 13 x 8
#   Trade_Date          B_S   Lots_Total Avg_Price   atr first_term second_term difference
#   <dttm>              <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 2017-12-11 00:00:00 B             88     3591   43.3       43.3        43.3      0    
# 2 2017-12-11 00:00:00 S             88     3586   43.3       43.3        43.3      2.61 
# 3 2017-12-08 00:00:00 B            176     3594   40.7       40.7        43.3      0    
# 4 2017-12-08 00:00:00 S            176     3599.  40.7       40.7        40.7      0.382
# 5 2017-12-07 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3       40.3        40.7     -1.53 
# 6 2017-12-06 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   41.8       41.8        40.3      1.55 
# 7 2017-12-05 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   40.3       40.3        41.8      0.754
# 8 2017-12-04 00:00:00 B             44     3563   39.5       39.5        40.3      0    
# 9 2017-12-04 00:00:00 S             44     3569   39.5       39.5        39.5     -3.21 
#10 2017-12-01 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   42.7       42.7        39.5     -3.47 
#11 2017-11-30 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   46.2       46.2        42.7     -0.971
#12 2017-11-29 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.2       47.2        46.2     -0.118
#13 2017-11-28 00:00:00 NA            NA       NA   47.3       47.3        47.2     NA
```

Comment: I see the problem with grouping the data. However, when I run the first solution: dat %>%
  arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>%
  mutate(first_term = atr, second_term = lag(atr, default = first(atr)),
         difference = atr - lag(atr, default = first(atr))) the difference column is all zeros.

Comment: When I run the second solution:                                              
graph_data_frame1 %>%
arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>%
  mutate(first_term = atr, second_term = lag(atr, default = first(atr)),
         difference = atr - lead(atr))

the difference column has 0 for 3 rows and NA for other rows. Do I need to ungroup the data before running the statements?

Comment: Sure, you must ungroup it first, otherwise it performs all the operations inside the group, that why it produce such output, as I assume. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually when I checked the results again ungroup doesn't help with my data. However, when I run the first solution: dat %>% arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>% mutate(first_term = atr, second_term = lag(atr, default = first(atr)), difference = atr - lag(atr, default = first(atr))) the difference column is all zeros. When I run the second solution: graph_data_frame1 %>% arrange(desc(Trade_Date)) %>% mutate(first_term = atr, second_term = lag(atr, default = first(atr)), difference = atr - lead(atr)) the difference column has 0 for 3 rows and NA for other rows.

Comment: When you print your results to console, `tibble` by default prints out a groups defined on it. After the `# tibble ....` at the beginning of the output, do you see something like `Groups: ...`? If yes, it means that data are grouped. Try to add `ungroup()` after the `data %>%` for each case.